# Swift: AnyObject cast to Float failed

Tags: swift, casting, anyobject

```
let json = [
    "left" : 18,
    "deadline" : "May 10",
    "progress" : 0.6
] as [String: AnyObject]

let ss = json["progress"] as? Float
let sss = json["progress"] as? Double
print("ss = \(ss)\n  sss = \(sss)")
```

I have no idea why the `ss` shows nil while `sss` shows `0.599999998`. Why does casting to `Float` get nil? Do you guys have some methods so that I can get the correct result?

Comment: You should use Any instead of AnyObject  `let json:[String: Any] = [ "left" : 18, "deadline" : "May 10", "progress" : 0.6 ]`

Comment: If you would like to store a Float instead of a Double you would need to specify it  `Float(0.6)` otherwise the compiler will infer the type (Double)

Comment: I have tried to use Any, but it made no sense.

Comment: Using AnyObject is what doesn't make any sense. Float is a struct not AnyObject. It is stored as NSNumber if you use AnyObject

Comment: using AnyObject the correct approach to get a Float would be `(json["progress"] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. `"progress" : Float(0.6)`. Changing to this makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Note: no need to cast `let js:[String: Any]   = [ "left" : 18, "deadline" : "May 10", "progress" : Float(0.6) ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `0.6` is a `Double` *literal value*. As such, you can't cast it to `Float` (you need to *convert* it).

Try this instead:

```
let f = Float(json["progress"] as! Double)
```

Or, if you aren't really sure what type of number this `AnyObject` holds, the safer approach would be:

```
let f = (json["progress"] as! NSNumber).floatValue
```

Of course, those `as!` above will crash *hard* if the json value is missing *or* you misjudge the expected type. Use the `as?` operator instead if you feel otherwise :)

---

**Casting crash course**. When casting a known `Double` value to a `Float`, the compiler gives us a nice heads up about this:

```
let d = 0.6
let f = d as? Float
```

> warning: cast from 'Double' to unrelated type 'Float' always fails

Comment: @LeoDabus Good Leaf here is still learning his way around Swift... failing fast helps a lot!  Silent errors not so much...

Comment: @LeoDabus To be clear, if we leave it as `Float?`, he is gonna be using `?` all the way and will be completely lost when his code finally crashes down the line. Just look at all those SO newbie questions out there wrongly using `?` like crazy haha...

Comment: @LeoDabus I somehow feel he is still on that *testing* phase of yours... :-) Anyway, thanks for the detailed feedback man!