# Cast Any to Float always fails in swift4.1

Tags: swift, downcast, swift4.1

In the former version, to get a float value from a `[String: Any]` dictionary, I can use `let float = dict["somekey"] as? Float`, but in swift4.1, it doesn't work. It seems the type of `dict["somekey"]` has been implicitly inferred as `Double` before I get it, so casting from `Double` to `Float` always fails. I wonder if it is a new characteristic or just a bug.

--Here is the update.

I re-downloadeded an Xcode9.2 and did some experiments, now I think I figure out what's going on. Here is the test code:

```
let dict: [String : Any] = ["key": 0.1]

if let float: Float = dict["key"] as? Float {
    print(float)
} else {
    print("nil")
}

let dict1: [String : Any] = ["key": NSNumber(value: 0.2)]

if let float: Float = dict1["key"] as? Float {
    print(float)
} else {
    print("nil")
}

let number = NSNumber(value: 0.3)
if let float: Float = number as? Float {
    print(float)
} else {
    print("nil")
}

let number1 = NSNumber(floatLiteral: 0.4)
if let float = number1 as? Float {
    print(float)
} else {
    print("nil")
}
```

Running this code in Playground of Swift4 and Swift4.1, the results are different. In Swift4, the results are `nil` `0.2` `0.3` `0.4`, and In Swift4.1 the results are `nil` `nil` `nil` `nil`. From the result, I can learn two points:
1. When we convert JSON data into a `[String : Any] dictionary` with the `JSONSerialization` class, the numeric value is saved as an `NSNumber` object, but not `Int`, `Double` or `Float`.
2. In Swift4, we can use `let float = NSNumberOjbect as? Float` to get a `Float` value, but in Swift4.1 we can't. But still, we can get `Int` or `Double` value in this way, either in Swift4 or Swift4.1.
Finally again, is this a new feature or a bug? If someone knows, can you guys show up the announcement link?

Comment: Did the compiler say it will always fail? Or did you find out that it always fails by running the code multiple times?

Comment: The behavior is already found in Swift 3, when `dict` is a Swift native `[String: Any]`. When an `NSDictionary` is imported as `[String: Any]`, the behavior is different.

Comment: A same line of code, like `guard let float: Float = dict["key"] as? Float else { return }`, can get a float value in swift4.0, but exit in swift4.1.

Comment: See answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623530/swift-anyobject-cast-to-float-failed/43623573#43623573

Comment: @Sweeper I tried this "let float: Float? = 0.123 as? Float", and the complier said it will always fail. Now the only way I can get a float value is to use force-casting `Float(someDoubleValue)`.

Comment: @Ankit Jayaswal It's works. Thank you. I think this coding style is more rigorous.

Comment: The same code always fails in Swift 3, when `dict` is a Swift native `Dictionary`. Have you really tested the code with Swift native `Dictionary` in Swift 4.0?

Comment: For your updated part, check this: [NSNumber bridging and Numeric types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0170-nsnumber_bridge.md). The article shows the feature is implemented in Swift 4, but the implementation seems to be incomplete in Swift 4 and Swift 4.1 shows the right behavior. Try your sample codes with value `0.5` or `0.25`, which can be represented in `Float` exactly.

Answer (score 10):

You need to distinguish two cases (in Swift 3, it was three cases):

- `Any` containing a Swift native `Double`
- `Any` containing an `NSNumber`

(In Swift 3, there was [*type preserving `NSNumber` case*](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0139-bridge-nsnumber-and-nsvalue.md) other than the normal `NSNumber`.)

---

When you create a native Swift `Dictionary` such as `[String: Any]`, and set `Double` value in a normal way like this in your update:

```
let dict: [String : Any] = ["key": 0.1]
```

In this case, `Any` holds the metadata representing `Double` and the raw value `0.1` as `Double`.

And casting `Any` holding `Double` to `Float` always fails. As `Double` to `Float` cannot be converted with `as`-castings.

```
let dblValue: Double = 0.1
if let fltValue = dblValue as? Float { //<-Cast from 'Double' to unrelated type 'Float' always fails
    print(fltValue)
} else {
    print("Cannot convert to Float")
}
//->Cannot convert to Float
```

---

But, in case of `Any` holding `NSNumber`, as always happens when the `Array` or `Dictionary` is bridged from `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, the behaviors are different between former Swifts and Swift 4.1.

The result of `JSONSerialization` matches this case.

In former Swifts, (normal) `NSNumber` to `Float` was an always-success operation.

And in Swift 4.1, the behavior has changed with the new feature which I have shown in my comment:

SE-0170 [NSNumber bridging and Numeric types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0170-nsnumber_bridge.md)

---

I omit the third case once found in Swift 3, it's past.

But it is very important how you get your `Dictionary` or `Array`, and how you set the value to them, to solve the issue `Any` to `Float`.

---

***Finally again, is this a new feature or a bug? If someone knows, can you guys show up the announcement link?***

This is a new feature, not a bug. See the link above, and related threads below.

[Unable to bridge NSNumber to Float Swift 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49641887/6541007)

[Unexpected behavior when casting an NSNumber to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49688983/6541007)

Comment: if ["key": 0.1] then converting to Float failing, but ["key": 1.0], then working successfully, what might be the reason behind this