# JSON parsing float in swift4.1 has unexpected behaviour

Tags: swift, swift4.1

A simple function that parse json variable and returns a float.

```
func parseMyFloat(jsonString: String) -> Float? {
    if let data = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true),
        let parsedJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String : Any] {
        if let parsedJSON = parsedJSON {
            return parsedJSON["myFloat"] as? Float
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now if i try this.

```
print(parseMyFloat(jsonString: "{\"myFloat\":23.2322998046875}"))
// output: 23.2322998
```

output is fine but if I change `23.2322998046875` value to `23.2322998046` func returns nil.

```
print(parseMyFloat(jsonString: "{\"myFloat\":23.2322998}"))
// output: nil
```

Then I tried casting Any to Float which doesn't work.

```
let dic:[String : Any] = ["float1" : 23.2322998046875, "float2" : 23.2322998]
print(dic["float1"] as? Float) // prints nil
print(dic["float2"] as? Float) // prints nil
```

I have lots of float in my code, so after migrating to swift 4.1 I am having this issue.

Should I change all `Float`'s to `Double`'s ?? And `23.2322998046875` why works and why not `23.2322998`??

Comment: For a partial answer please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607492/cast-any-to-float-always-fails-in-swift4-1/49703477#49703477

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected behavior when casting an NSNumber to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688983/unexpected-behavior-when-casting-an-nsnumber-to-float)

Comment: @MartinR can you please suggest any work around? Or only option is to change all the floats to doubles? Or i add special checks for floots and use floatValue method of NSNumber? I just reverted back to swift 4 just because of this issue. There are lots of flaot parsing in our project. Thanks

Comment: @Bilal: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49642539/1187415 ?

Comment: @MartinR Yeah I have tried that and it works too. But I'm worried because I have to modify lots of code in lots of classes. It's looks like I don't have any other option :(

Comment: @Bilal: Yes, I think so (and I am inclined to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/49642539/1187415).

Comment: @MartinR sure you can close it. One last thing, any explanation about why `23.2322998046875` works and why `23.2322998` doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your function as it is and don't want to modify the return value to `Double`, you can simply parse the JSON value as `Double` to avoid the [issue of casting Any to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607492/cast-any-to-float-always-fails-in-swift4-1/49703477#49703477) as explained in the comments and then convert the `Double` to `Float` before returning it.

```
func parseMyFloat(jsonString: String) -> Float? {
    if let data = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true), let parsedJSON = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)) as? [String : Any], let myDouble = parsedJSON["myFloat"] as? Double {
            return Float(myDouble)
    }
    return nil
}

parseMyFloat(jsonString: "{\"myFloat\":23.2322998046875}") //23.2323998
parseMyFloat(jsonString: "{\"myFloat\":23.2322998}") //23.2323998
```

Comment: Does that have an advantage over `(parsedJSON["myFloat"] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue` (as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49642539/1187415)?

Comment: @MartinR I don't think so, I posted my solution as an answer rather than a comment to show OP how they can avoid having to change any code outside the function's scope

Comment: Thanks, Actually code in the question was just a sample code for the question to simplify the problem. But Thanks.