# Swift Unable to bridge NSNumber to Float

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsnumber, bridging

So I have a NSArrays loaded with for pitch and yaw values saved on a `Shot` object.

```
@interface Shot : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pitch;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *yaw;
```

I am trying to do some number crunching in swift and running into a very weird problem:

```
let pitch = Array(shot.recoil_pitch[0..<10]) as! [Float]
let yaw = Array(shot.recoil_yaw[0..<10]) as! [Float]
```

For some reason that I can't figure out, the first line runs fine. The second line, however, throws a `Fatal error: Unable to bridge NSNumber to Float`.

When I inspect `shot.recoil_pitch[0..<10]` in the debugger I get:

```
- 0 : 0
- 1 : -0.1355667114257812
- 2 : -2.584976196289062
- 3 : -2.238974571228027
- 4 : -1.606719017028809
- 5 : -1.54025936126709
- 6 : -1.570234298706055
- 7 : -1.544057846069336
- 8 : -1.323789596557617
- 9 : -1.073002815246582
```

and when I inspect the `shot.recoil_yaw[0..<10]` I get:

```
- 0 : 0
- 1 : 0.017406463623046875
- 2 : -0.07871246337890625
- 3 : 0.004611968994140625
- 4 : 0.0446014404296875
- 5 : -0.0008544921875
- 6 : 0.010448455810546875
- 7 : 0.01015472412109375
- 8 : -0.002346038818359375
- 9 : -0.0569610595703125
```

Any ideas on why I might be getting this error?

Comment: When you inspect `recoil_yaw` does it give you any type information? If you are dealing with stuff from Objective-C maybe it would be best to cast them to the native Objective-C class `NSNumber` and then map them to `Float` using the member `floatValue`.

Comment: What is the return type of subscript on `recoil_yaw`? Better use `map` instead of force casting as `Array(shot.recoil_pitch[0..<10]).map{ $0.floatValue }`

Comment: Also this may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019421/1484378

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688983/unexpected-behavior-when-casting-an-nsnumber-to-float

Comment: @Kamran - That’s right, but he won’t be able to just call `floatValue` that without either (a) casting `$0` to `NSNumber`; or (b) using lightweight generics in his Objective-C header, e.g. `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<NSNumber *> *recoil_pitch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to reproduce this problem with this simple example:

```
var arr = [NSNumber(value: 1.3 as Float), NSNumber(value: 2.7)]

// This works
let x = arr.map { $0.floatValue }
print(x)
```

> ```
> [1.3, 2.7]
> ```

```
// This fails with error 'Fatal error: Unable to bridge NSNumber to Float'
let y = arr as! [Float]
print(y)
```

As explained in the [duplicate's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689243/1630618), you can't cast an `NSNumber` to `Float` if the cast doesn't preserve the exact value.  `Double(2.7)` loses precision when converted to `Float`, so the cast fails.  Had I chosen `2.5` instead of `2.7` for the `Double`, the cast would have worked.

Accessing the value with `.floatValue` works because it uses the property of `NSNumber` to produce the `Float` value.

Comment: The problem is not that the underlying value is a Double, but that this Double is not exactly preserved when converted to a Float.   Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689243/1187415. As an example, `var arr = [NSNumber(value: 1.3 as Float), NSNumber(value: 2.5)]` can be cast to `[Float]` without problems.