# Unexpected behavior when casting an NSNumber to Float

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

After upgrading to Xcode 9.3 (9E145) my App showed some unexpected behavior. It seems that the issue is with a cast of an NSNumber to a Float. I use the `as` type cast operator for this. See the following example.

```
let n = NSNumber.init(value: 1.12)
let m = NSNumber.init(value: 1.00)

let x = n as? Float
let y = m as? Float

let xd = n as? Double

let z = Float(truncating: n)
```

Here, the first cast fails, i.e. `x == nil`. The second cast succeeds and the instantiation of a Float with the `init:truncating` constructor also succeeds, i.e. `z == 1.12`. The cast of n to a Double succeeds, which, to me, makes no sense at all.

Can anyone explain this behavior to me? I.e. can anyone give me a good reason why the cast of n to a Float fails? Is this a bug? If this is intended behavior, can you please reference the location in the Swift documentation that describes this?

Comment: why you are using typecasting using as? why not use NSNumber's  floatValue & doubleValue method??

Comment: @rishi : in my App i am using the as? operator because the value to be casted is actually an Any? returned by a web service (firebase). Firebase uses NSNumber to represent a numeric value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a consequence of [SE-0170 NSNumber bridging and Numeric types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0170-nsnumber_bridge.md), implemented in Swift 4:

> `as?` for `NSNumber` should mean "Can I safely express the value stored in this opaque box called a NSNumber as the value I want?".

`1.12` is a floating point literal, and inferred as a `Double`, so `NSNumber(value: 1.12)` is  “boxing” the 64-bit floating point value
closest to `1.12`. Converting that to a 32-bit `Float` does not
preserve this value:

```
let n = NSNumber(value: 1.12)
let x = Float(truncating: n) // Or: let x = n.floatValue
let nn = NSNumber(value: x)
print(n == nn) // false
```

On the other hand, `1.0` can be represented exactly as a `Float`:

```
let m = NSNumber(value: 1.0)
let y = m.floatValue
let mm = NSNumber(value: y)
print(m == mm) // true
```

and that is why casting `m as? Float` succeeds. Both

```
n.floatValue
Float(truncating: n)
```

can be used to ”truncate” the number to the closest representable
32-bit floating point value.

Comment: How can I cast `[NSArray]` to `[[Float]]`? Do I have to cast to `Double` first and use the `Float` initializer in a for loop or is there a simpler solution?