# Reading a float or double from json with swift

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to read a json file with swift and it contains a field with 0.97.

If I tried to cast the field to a float, it would return nil, but if I were to cast it to a double, it would return the correct value. However, the only difference I could find on double and float was that double is 64-bit while float is 32-bit. I am wondering what is causing the difference.

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue that casting Any to Float has issues. See [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607492/cast-any-to-float-always-fails-in-swift4-1). Just cast to Double.

Comment: Why not close as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me:

```
var jsonString = "{\n" +
    "\"float\":0.97,\n" +
    "\"double\":0.97\n" +
    "}\n"

struct Outcome: Decodable {
    let float: Float?
    let double: Double?
}
let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let outcome = try JSONDecoder().decode(Outcome.self, from: data)
print(outcome) // Outcome(float: Optional(0.97), double: Optional(0.97))
```